# return value from function is None and can't return first key

Tags: python, recursion

I have a seemingly simple recursive function here that loops through a dictionary of dictionaries. I would like to print my value v as I am already doing and I would like to return the first key that is associated with this key:value pair. In this case, the code outputs `v = 'hi'` and `None`. I'm not sure why it keeps returning None. I set the k variable to an empty string outside of the function. K in this case should be `'six'`. Also, I would like the code to somehow return `'five'` since it is the first key but I am not sure if that is possible. Can anyone assist? I apologize in advance for any confusion with the keys either. Here, the code should be returning k = 'six'. I'm not sure how I would go about getting the key of `{'six': 'hi'}` returned.

```
my_dict = {'one': {'two': 'hello'}, 'three': {'four': 'hey'}, 'five': {'six': 'hi'}}
k = ''
numero = 'six'

def find_location(d):
    for k, v in d.iteritems():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            find_location(v)
        else:
            if numero == k:
                print 'this is k: {}'.format(k)
                print v
                return k


def print_return(func):
    print func


x = find_location(my_dict)
print_return(x)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other answer is correct, you aren't returning the result from when your function recurses.

With that addition, however, your function still won't return the answer you want because it never moves beyond the first iteration of your loop. If the first `key != 'six'`, the function will still return `None`.

```
def find_location(d):
    for k, v in d.items():
      if isinstance(v, dict):
          key = find_location(v)
          if (key == numero):
            print(v)
            return k
      else:
        return k
```

The above function prints 'hi' and returns 'five'

Comment: Good observation.

Comment: yes nice work! Thank you. now time to apply this to my yaml and see if it works. I always try to simplify things a bit when uploading to stackoverflow

Answer (score 6):

You must pass the result of the recursive call up the stack:

```
if isinstance(v, dict):
    return find_location(v)  # note the 'return'
```

Without the `return`, the line is just a statement that calls the function but doesn't return its result (or ends the surrounding function). And without a return statement, a function implicitly returns `None`.